# Does under/over sampling lead to data leakage?

Tags: unbalanced-classes, oversampling

I could not imagine how can we applied over/under sampling in practice.

Let's say, a client gave me 1 million of labeled samples, and 1000 of unlabeled samples to classify. There are two classes `good` and `bad`, which the ratio if 99:1.

I can perform under/over sampling on the labeled dataset, but how can I do that in the unlabeled dataset where I do not know the real label?

It seems to me that, during over/under sampling, we foresee the datasets and it is data leakage.

Am I wrong? If so, please give some explanations.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: I don't know what the question is about.

Comment: the question is about, 1) how can we use over/under sampling in practice and 2) does over/under sampling leads to data leakage?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "data leakage."  The [standard meaning](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22data+leakage%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) doesn't seem to apply here.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing the labeled and unlabeled data.

You have 1 million labeled samples: what percentage of the 1 million are `good` and what percentage are `bad`? If that ratio is high, to use your example numbers 99% good to 1% bad, you may need to consider over/under sampling before training.

From the 1 million, you would hold out a test set, which you might want to pick at random but using stratification so that it includes both `good` and `bad` samples. If the ratio between good and bad is extreme, you would then consider over-sampling the minority (labeled, not in your holdout) class or under-sampling the majority (labeled, not in your holdout) class to create your actual training set.

Your 1000 unlabeled samples are what they are, and after you've trained and tested your model, you would feed them into the model and your results are your results. Perhaps the client knows the labels for these 1000, but that doesn't enter your calculation.

So, the ratio of labeled to unlabeled is not meaningful. In the context of unbalanced data, it's the ratio between the labels that matters.

[If you do something that crosses the training-data/test-data line, you are at risk of data leakage. That's a different concept. And your data may itself may have leakage in it due to the way the client records it, which is a frustrating part of analytics.]

Comment: Hi @Wayne, thanks for that. So my concern is, if I built my classifier based on balanced dataset (via under sampling for instance) and it works well, the classifier might fail on real imbalanced dataset (the 1K events). Is it possible? Suppose that the distribution of good/bad are the same for both 1M and 1K dataset.

Comment: More precise: I am training a classifier in a balanced dataset (created via under sampling, so suppose that my training set includes 5K good and 5K bad samples) then validating this classifier in an imbalanced dataset (1K dataset). Is it a good way to do so?